# php - value replacing between two multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array1
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [accNo] => 000000
                [accTypeCode] => C
                [accName] => something
                [accCurrency] => BDT
                [branchCode] => 101
                [branchName] => empty
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [accNo] => 0000
                [accTypeCode] => C
                [accName] => something
                [accCurrency] => BDT
                [branchCode] => 101
                [branchName] => empty
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [accNo] => 0000
                [accTypeCode] => L
                [accName] => something
                [accCurrency] => BDT
                [branchCode] => 999
                [branchName] => empty
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [accNo] => 00000
                [accTypeCode] => L
                [accName] => something
                [accCurrency] => BDT
                [branchCode] => 999
                [branchName] => empty
            )

    )




Array2
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [branchCode] => 101
                [ATMName] => Agrabad
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [branchCode] => 999
                [ATMName] => Azimpur
            )

    )
```

these are my two arrays array1 and array2. Now what I need to do is in array1 where branchCode is 101 there branchName `empty` will be replaced by the `ATMName` of array2 where branchCode is 101 and same will be for 999. Hope I have made my question clear ...

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or we just should write codes for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havent tried it yet,but mostly it should work.

```
for($c1=0;$c1<count($array1);$c1++)
{
    if($array1[$c1]['branchName']=="empty")
    {
          for($c2=0;$c2<count($array2);$c2++)
          {
               if($array1[$c1]['branchCode']==$array2[$c2]['branchCode'])
               {
                    $array1[$c1]['branchName']=$array2[$c2]['ATMName'];            
               }
          }

    }

}
```

Do let me know if it worked!

Comment: I think the if condition where branchName == empty is not necessary.... it worked though ...

Comment: @jishan I assumed that,you can remove it if you dont need it.Hope it helped